# Rails 4, Create vCard with rqrcode gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, qr-code

I'm looking for some advice on the best way forward with my app which i have began to integrate [whomwah/rqrcode](https://github.com/whomwah/rqrcode) for the first time. Im a bit of a beginner in rails but keen to dive in so forgive any glaring errors!

I going to create Vcard with rqrcode. Search in google not find any document.

How can i do Vcard with rqrcode?

thanks and much appreciated

CODE:

Comment: I don't understand. What does a gem for creating QR codes have to do with vCard? Why do you think you can do that?

Comment: yes @awendt, rqrcode possible to can create vCard.. any other QR codes gem implement to vCard..

Answer (score 1):

I just used the api of [QR code generator](http://goqr.me/#t=vcard). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it helps another person looking for the same question, I've just implemented it.

It's not the most elegant solution, but it works.

In a Rails view use this:

```rb
qrcode = RQRCode::QRCode.new("BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
TEL;type=HOME;type=VOICE;type=pref:#{ member.mobile_number }
FN:#{ member.full_name }
N:#{ member.last_name };#{ member.first_name };;;
EMAIL;type=INTERNET;type=pref:#{ member.email }
ADR;type=HOME;type=pref:;;;;;;#{ member.country }
ORG:#{ member.account_name }
NOTE:#{ ['line1', 'line2'].join('\n') }
END:VCARD") %>

  <%= raw qrcode.as_svg(
    color: "000",
    shape_rendering: "crispEdges",
    module_size: 4,
    standalone: true,
    use_path: true
  ) %>
```